# Ubuntu running slow on my good machine!

Tags: 64-bit, 13.04, performance

**Its fixed now :)**

I just installed Ubuntu on my PC. I lag a lot. My pc runs all other OS' at high speed, but ubuntu lags like hell. It worked on my old laptop.

My Specs:

- XFX AMD Radeon HD 7870 Black Edition
- AMD A8-3800 APU
- 2x4 GB 1333 MHz Ram
- 1TB Harddrive

I installed the latest version of Ubuntu. 13.04 I believe.

I run Windows and other linux distros really fast, so why does Ubuntu lag?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what version of Ubuntu you are running?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release, and architecture did you install?

Comment: The newest one. 13.0.4 or something like that

Comment: There is no 13.0.4. Maybe 13.04. Check in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) with this command: `lsb_release -a` to be sure.

Comment: Ye, it's version 13.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my fresh install of 12.04 running slow?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159819/why-is-my-fresh-install-of-12-04-running-slow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you have the drivers needed, so [open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it), and run this:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install fglrx
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Then reboot.

If ubuntu is still slow, you might want to change your desktop environment to something like [LXDE](http://www.howtogeek.com/107368/how-to-install-the-lightweight-lxde-desktop-on-ubuntu/), [XFCE](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/xfce), [KDE](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/kde), or [GNOME](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-get-complete-gnome-3-desktop-in.html) (though GNOME under ubuntu can be slower than unity, partly due to the excessive patching made by canonical).

Comment: Restarting my pc to see if it works.

Comment: Ubuntu runs faster now, but in the left lower corner it says Unsupported hardware.

Comment: @JonasRothmannHjalager Please see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206558/how-to-remove-the-amd-testing-use-only-watermark